# SmartTarget/FredHopper Configuration Log - to see which claims are passed in the FH call

Tags: smarttarget, ambient-data-framework

Good Afternoon,

I am working in a SmartTarget project (Tridion 2011 SP1/ ST 2011 SP2), I have all the cartridges configured (the ones i need), and I want to know how I can turn on the log to see the the collection of claims that are passed in the FredHopper Call.

At this moment i've setup the smartTarget Log in the Delivery Web App, this is the log I am getting right now :

```
    2014-01-13 16:15:29,512 DEBUG Query - initializing web service client for: http://CMS:8180/fredhopper-ws/services/FASWebService?wsdl
    2014-01-13 16:15:30,709 TRACE Stopwatches - Performance result [thread: 32] 'FredhopperWSInit': 1197 milliseconds(LONG).
    2014-01-13 16:15:30,710 DEBUG Query - Constructing Fredhopper query
    2014-01-13 16:15:30,739 TRACE Stopwatches - Performance result [thread: 32] 'Query.InitParseEntityModel': 29 milliseconds.
    2014-01-13 16:15:30,740 DEBUG Query - Executing query: fh_location=//catalog01/en_US/categories<{catalog01_tcm_0_9_1_tcm_9_9_4}&fh_view=home
    2014-01-13 16:15:30,842 TRACE Stopwatches - Performance result [thread: 32] 'Query.GetAll': 102 milliseconds.
    2014-01-13 16:15:30,848 TRACE Stopwatches - Performance result [thread: 32] 'Query.CreateResultSet': 5 milliseconds.
    2014-01-13 16:15:30,848 TRACE Stopwatches - Performance result [thread: 32] 'Query.ExecuteFredhopperQuery': 138 milliseconds.
    2014-01-13 16:15:30,851 DEBUG Query - Query returned 0 item(s)
    2014-01-13 16:15:30,851 DEBUG Query - Query returned 1 promotion(s):
    2014-01-13 16:15:30,859 DEBUG Query - Promotion: [HomePage Promotions] with [2] number of items for region [PromosRegion]
```

I remember that once I was able to turn-on the level of logging i am trying to accomplish now. but i lost that environment (the amazon instance got corrupted), so i missed the configuration.

Any help would be very appreciedted.

Regards,
yeremy.

Update 1 [01-14-14]

Actually, the Log that I already had configured (in the delivery Side/Java App) at the moment i wrote this question was :

```
    <appender name="rollingSmartTargetLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/smarttarget.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>${log.history}</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <prudent>true</prudent>
    </appender> 



    <!-- All Java based smarttarget -->
    <logger name="com.tridion.smarttarget" level="ALL">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingSmartTargetLog"/>
    </logger>
    <!-- specific one for ambientdata -->
    <logger name="com.tridion.smarttarget.ambientdata" level="ALL">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingSmartTargetLog"/>
    </logger>
    <!-- all .Net logs through Juggernet -->
    <logger name="Tridion.SmartTarget" level="ALL">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingSmartTargetLog"/>
    </logger>
```

So, it should be another configution. maybe at FH/ST side.

**[Updated 01-15-14]**

The above configuration is enough to accomplish what i wanted, but the problem (in my environment) is that for some reason my Java app is not getting access to the ClaimStore. [here more details](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4176/adf-claimstore-not-available-null-in-java-application) about this issue

Comment: Just a note that in SmartTarget 2014, the query is logged with the INFO level. So you don't have to set the log level all the way to DEBUG to see the queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this information from `Content Delivery\configuration\samples\logback_sample.xml` on your CD layout.

You may then copy the `appender` and `logger` sections into your existing logback.xml.

Comment: That's this one: https://gist.github.com/jhorsman/8419553

Comment: No, that's the one from Tridion - I'm talking about the sample from SmartTarget. He managed to install so I'm sure he has access to it :)

Comment: Oops, my bad. This I think this is the right one. Sharing for everyone else reading along. https://gist.github.com/jhorsman/8420871

Comment: I did this before the writing the question, this configuration is enough to see the claims that are being added. the problem was that i am not getting access to the ClaimStore from my Java App that uses SmartTarget, I wrote another question about that problem : http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4176/adf-claimstore-not-available-null-in-java-application

Answer (score 3):

Here's the snippets from my log file (logback.xml) that I think will help you configure your environment:

```
<appender name="rollingSmartTargetLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/smarttarget.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
      <maxHistory>${log.history}</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <prudent>true</prudent>
</appender>
```

and here's the logger:

```
<logger name="com.tridion.smarttarget" level="${log.level}">
    <appender-ref ref="rollingSmartTargetLog" /> 
</logger>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this one for logging during SmartTarget development. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jhorsman/8420350) for the full logback.xml.

```
    <appender name="rollingSmartTargetLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/smarttarget.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>${log.history}</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <prudent>true</prudent>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.telenor.tridion.claims" level="${log.level}">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingSmartTargetLog"/>
    </logger>

    <!-- Tridion SmartTarget -->
    <logger name="com.tridion.smarttarget" level="${log.level}">
            <appender-ref ref="rollingSmartTargetLog"/>
    </logger>
    <!-- SmartTarget .Net logs through Juggernet -->
    <logger name="Tridion.SmartTarget" level="${log.level}">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingSmartTargetLog"/>
    </logger>

    <!-- Tridion AmbientDataFramework -->
    <logger name="com.tridion.ambientdata" level="${log.level}">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingSmartTargetLog"/>
    </logger>
    <!--<logger name="com.tridion.smarttarget.ambientdata" level="${log.level}">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingSmartTargetLog"/>
    </logger>-->
```