# ADF ClaimStore not available (null) in Java Application

Tags: java, ambient-data-framework

Good Morning!

This is my scenario :

I created a cartridge and I successfully added the new claims to the ClaimStore. I am sure about it because i am using the ClaimPageAspx.aspx page to list all the claims that i have, so i can see the new claims.

The problem is that when I try to access to the ClaimStore from a **Java Application**, I am getting a null value for the ClaimStore, the following are some details about my environment :

- I have a totally operating application using the ClaimStore in .Net in the same environment (same computer).
- I copied the entire bin/lib and bin/config from my .net app to my WEB-INF/lib and WEB-INF/classes respectively.
- I followed the configuration from the  [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US&action=search&query=ambient%2520data%2520framework&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1389769214347&currentQuery=ambient%2520data%2520framework&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_8B902BCF2C1648C0B84664E3DBB79FD0&query=ambient%2520data%2520framework&scope=&filename=EnablingADFOnTheJSPWebSite.xml&docid=task_8B902BCF2C1648C0B84664E3DBB79FD0&inner_id=&tid=ad30f43b-4b2f-48cf-95b2-353f889dc671&addHistory=true&resource=) (login required).

**Java Code**

```
    ClaimStore claims = AmbientDataContext.getCurrentClaimStore();
    //claims is always null!!!
    if(claims != null)
    {
        Map<URI, Object> x = claims.getAll();
        for (Map.Entry<URI, Object> entry : x.entrySet())
        {
            //print the claims
        }
    }
```

**cd_ambient_config.xml**

```
<Cartridges>       
    <Cartridge File="cd_webservice_preview_cartridge.xml"/>
    <Cartridge File="footprint_cartridge_conf.xml"/>

    <Cartridge File="smarttarget_cartridge_conf.xml"/>
    <Cartridge File="/client_cookie_cartridge.xml" />
    <Cartridge File="/session_cartridge_conf.xml"/>
</Cartridges>
<!--<ClaimStoreProvider>com.tridion.siteedit.preview.PreviewClaimStoreProvider</ClaimStoreProvider>-->
```

**web.xml (java application)**

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Ambient Data Framework</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AmbientDataServletFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Ambient Data Framework</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Content Delivery Web service</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
```

**Logback Configuration**

```
    <appender name="rollingSmartTargetLog2" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/smarttarget.others.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>${log.history}</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <prudent>true</prudent>
    </appender> 

    <logger name="com.tridion.ambientdata" level="${log.level}">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingSmartTargetLog2"/>
    </logger>
```

**Log Results Java App (failing)**

```
    2014-01-15 08:18:02,063 DEBUG AmbientDataServletFilter - init
    2014-01-15 08:18:02,069 DEBUG AmbientDataContext - Setting current ambient data context: com.tridion.ambientdata.web.WebContext
```

**Log Results from .Net App (working!)**

```
    2014-01-15 08:22:36,598 WARN  AmbientDataContext - There is no current ambient data context - the ambient data framework is not properly initialised
    2014-01-15 08:22:36,615 DEBUG AmbientDataContext - Setting current ambient data context: com.tridion.ambientdata.web.WebContext
    2014-01-15 08:22:37,120 DEBUG ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:response:cookie:generation, value=true
    2014-01-15 08:22:37,124 DEBUG WebContext - setCurrentClaimStore: com.tridion.ambientdata.dotnet.DotNetClaimStore@326b9c84, thread: Thread-1
    2014-01-15 08:22:37,139 DEBUG ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:uri, value=/ClaimPageAspx.aspx
    2014-01-15 08:22:37,140 DEBUG ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:full_url, value=http://localhost:49/ClaimPageAspx.aspx
    2014-01-15 08:22:37,151 DEBUG ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:headers, value={cookie=[Ljava.lang.String;@36f0b7f8, cache-control=[Ljava.lang.String;@75be16f5, connection=[Ljava.lang.String;@12d56b37, host=[Ljava.lang.String;@7971f189, accept-language=[Ljava.lang.String;@27a897a9, accept=[Ljava.lang.String;@2d7cec96, user-agent=[Ljava.lang.String;@6490832e, accept-encoding=[Ljava.lang.String;@4b947496, pragma=[Ljava.lang.String;@7f724a9d}
    2014-01-15 08:22:37,151 DEBUG ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:cookies, value={TAFSessionId=tridion_d07e08e0-fabc-48c9-956e-28ffb2faeb69, ASP.NET_SessionId=ukccfpqsmpwypm2c33w4ouix, TAFTrackingId=tridion_97548887-5f98-429b-9761-fdab7e7d1aac}
    2014-01-15 08:22:37,152 DEBUG ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:parameters, value={CONTENT_TYPE=[Ljava.lang.String;@2880cac9, QUERY_STRING=[Ljava.lang.String;@1f8166e5}
    2014-01-15 08:22:37,153 DEBUG ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:server:variables, value={REMOTE_USER=, PATH_TRANSLATED=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Claims\ClaimPageAspx.aspx, SERVER_PORT=49, SCRIPT_NAME=/ClaimPageAspx.aspx, REMOTE_ADDR=::1, AUTH_TYPE=, SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1, REQUEST_METHOD=GET, DOCUMENT_ROOT=null, REMOTE_HOST=::1, SERVER_NAME=localhost, SECURE=false}
    2014-01-15 08:22:37,157 DEBUG ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:session:id, value=tridion_d07e08e0-fabc-48c9-956e-28ffb2faeb69
    2014-01-15 08:22:37,157 DEBUG ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:tracking:id, value=tridion_97548887-5f98-429b-9761-fdab7e7d1aac
    2014-01-15 08:22:37,164 DEBUG ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:session:attributes, value={Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.ClaimStore=Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.ClaimStore}
    2014-01-15 08:22:37,168 DEBUG ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:claim:client:concerned_mom, value=0
    2014-01-15 08:22:37,169 DEBUG ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:claim:client:finacially_constrained, value=0
    2014-01-15 08:22:37,170 DEBUG ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:claim:client:lead_form_submited, value=0
    2014-01-15 08:22:37,171 DEBUG ClaimStore - put: uri=taf:claim:client:young_achiever, value=0
    2014-01-15 08:22:37,256 DEBUG WebContext - setCurrentClaimStore: com.tridion.ambientdata.dotnet.DotNetClaimStore@326b9c84, thread: Thread-1
    2014-01-15 08:22:37,257 DEBUG WebContext - setCurrentClaimStore: null, thread: Thread-1
```

Sorry about the long of this question, but i did not want to leave any detail.

Thank in advance.

Have a good day!

Regards
yeremy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the servlet-name in your filter mapping might be the problem here:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Ambient Data Framework</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Content Delivery Web service</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

So your ADF Filter doesn't come into play for your Java app, since it seems to be mapped to the odata servlet instead.

Try removing the servlet-name and making the ADF filter act for all urls like this:

```
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Ambient Data Framework</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: @Nickoli, I am having the same issue. But I dont have the web.xml. Do you know where we can configure the same servlet?

Comment: What app server are you on? Web.xml is pretty standard to java web apps.

Comment: @NickoliRoussakov : Can you please look over http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/16510/classnotfoundexception-com-sdl-web-oauth-validator-oauth2requestvalidator